# Analytics Platform(AP) + Performance Testing + Need a Open Source tool to Test AP

Tags: selenium, performance, agile-testing, security-testing

We Developed a Application, where we can track the Analytics of the Users.
Like Installs, Uninstalls, Sessions, Events, Sending Notifications, Large scale of Information where we can Track down the Usage of the Different vendor apps.

But recently we are facing an issue with our SDK, Where we are slowing down the apps performance. Getting Negative feedback with the Clients.

So need a Open Source tool for testing the SDK issue. Where we are lagging.

Need your help. So share your ideas? How I can approach?

Answer (score 1):

Profiler tools are your friends, if the performance degradation was introduced by a recent commit you should be able to track it down, they might not be open source but normally they are a part of developer toolchain and they are free.

- iOS: [Performance Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html)
- Android: [Performance Profiling Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html)
- Windows Phone: [Performance Profiling on Windows Phone 8.1 with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/04/03/performance-profiling-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio/)

If you are using backend server to collect and store information and visualise it - it might be the case when there is nothing wrong with your SDK, it is the backend server causing delays as it is overloaded. In that case check its health and schedule performance testing for it as well. Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for the most outstanding open source load testing tools.